# Qual a diferença entre *var++ e *var += 1?

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, matemática, operadores

Estou escrevendo uma função com a assinatura: `int increment(int *val)`. Meu intuito é receber um ponteiro inteiro, incrementar seu valor em **1** e retornar essa valor.

O corpo da minha função estava o seguinte:

```
int increment(int *val)
{
    *val += 1; // Dessa maneira o valor de val é incrementado em 1.
    return *val;
}
```

Na linha comentada, quando eu utilizava o operador unário `++`, como em  `*val++;` eu recebia o endereço de memória alterado.

Porque ao usar o operador unário ele modifica o endereço de memória? Teoricamente não era para isso equivaler a `*val += 1`? Agradeço se houverem exemplos explicando.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Isto ocorre por causa da precedência de operadores.

O `+=` tem baixa precedência, então o operador de apontamento ocorre primeiro, depois ele faz incremento no valor apontado.

O `++` tem maior precedência, então primeiro ele incrementa o valor da variável `val` que é um ponteiro, depois ele aplica o operador de apontamento e pega o valor apontado por este endereço calculado. basta colocar parenteses para resolver o problema da precedência:

```
(*val)++;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/YMol9X). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/btyjobqo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Arithmetic.c).

[Tabela de precedência](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 6):

Isso acontece devido a ordem de precedência das operações. O operador de incremento (++,--) tem precedência sobre o operador *.

Portanto, para que funcione da maneira que você deseja, primeiro é preciso ter acesso ao conteúdo apontado pela variável **val**. Para isso você faz ***val**, logo depois você faz o incremento **++**.

Para que você consiga realizar nessa ordem, é necessário o uso de parênteses.

Veja:

```
(*val)++;
```